How do I uniquely format one of a few Lightning-card compenents?
I have multiple lightning-card components on the same page.  I can use the following css to format all of the cards but I only want to format one of the cards. Is there a way to format just one of the cards on the component?
Thanks!
:host {
  --sds-c-card-color-background: #db6f6f;
 }


You can give it a unique class or data attribute and then target that in your CSS.
Useing class:
<lightning-card class="custom-card" ...>
<!-- Your card content -->
</lightning-card>

CSS:
.custom-card {
--sds-c-card-color-background: #db6f6f;
}

Using data attribute:
<lightning-card data-custom-card ...>
<!-- Your card content -->
</lightning-card>

And in CSS:
[data-custom-card] {
--sds-c-card-color-background: #db6f6f;
}


Thank you so much!!
